# How to download some data or a file in blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating a blazor web-assembly that you can select a file and the web do some process's and changes and then return the file
I don't want to use javascript to download the file because it has file size limitation
Is there any way to download a file in blazor web assembly?
In Asp.net you can write a code like this :

```
public FileContentResult GetFile()
{
      return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("File location"), "application/octet-stream", "file.extension");
}
```

But I don't want to download from server

Comment: "*I don't want to use javascript to download*" and "*I don't want to download from server*". Well, what do you want then?

Comment: As I said, client select a file. Web assembly will read file's bytes and put them into a byte array. Now I want to download this array without using js and I don't want to send this array to server and download it from there

Comment: Depends how big the file is - for smaller files, you can generate a data uri and use it on an anchor tag to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Blazor WebAssembly already your code will run and live inside client's browser/device anyway, so any file or its byte(s) stream you received will be received, buffered into (again) client's memory anyway, unless you explicitly upload it to your server through say HTTP or SignalR connection.

Now, on how to actually take file from user's storage (through their consent and selection ofc) are laid here [ASP.NET Core Blazor file uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly).

Basically, in its very bare minimum, you'll need an `InputFile` component to actually prompt the user to select one or many files and a method to become the callback of that. Co-pasted from the same page, in your .razor file/Razor component, you'll need something like this for the very bare functional minimum

```
<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple />

@code {
    private void LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code handling 'e'   
    }
}
```